# 書籍のサンプルコードについて：「bounds」の意味、「[xxxx]()」の意味

Tags: swift

書籍のサンプルコードに関して、２点ご教示ください。
参考文献：iPhone/iPadプログラミングバイブル：著 布留川英一

```
//パズルゲームの作成
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   let BTN_START = 0
   let sCREEn = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
   // →Q1「この１文は、どういう文法を使って、何をアウトプットしようとしているのか？」

   var _GAMEVIEW: UIView?
   var _TITLELABEL: UILabel?
   var _piece = [UIImageView]()
   var _data = [Int]()
   // →Q2「上の２文の『[xxxx]()』はどういう意味（文法）でしょうか？」
   var _SHUFFLE: Int = 0

// 続く、、、、、、、、
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let sCREEn = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
// →Q1「この１文は、どういう文法を使って、何をアウトプットしようとしているのか？」
```

この質問の主眼は、「boundsの意味」にはありません。boundsの意味は、UIScreenのプロパティで、画面の四囲の座標ですが、詳しくはUIScreenのクラスリファレンスで調べる（Xcodeのヘルプウインドウからアクセス可）か、「UIScreen bounds」などをキーワードにして、ネット検索してください。
この質問の主眼は、3つあるドットにあります。習熟したプログラマでも気にする人は少ないと思いますが、3つとも意味が異なります。まず、この1行を3行に分割してみていきましょう。

```
let screen: UIScreen = UIScreen.mainScreen()
let screenRectangle: CGRect = screen.bounds
let screenSize: CGSize = screenRectangle.size
```

1行目のドット（.）は、Receiver（クラスあるいはインスタンス）とMethod（メソッド）を結びつけます。Receiverに対して、メソッドを実行しなさいという意味を持ちます。ここでは、UIScreenクラスに対し、メインのスクリーンインスタンスを返しなさいという命令をしています。PCやMacでは、複数のディスプレイを接続して、使用することができ、メインのスクリーンを取得するというのは、イメージしやすいですが、iPhone/iPadではむずかしいかもしれません。が、iPhone/iPadを、テレビゲームのコントローラにするという用途は、ありそうです。そういう使い方なら、マルチスクリーン環境ということになります。

2行目のドットは、screenインスタンスのProperty（プロパティ）boundsにアクセスする意味を持ちます。プロパティはメソッドと同様、値を返します。boundsは、CGRect型の値を返します。
3行目のドットは、Structure（構造体）CGRectのプロパティsizeにアクセスします。プロパティへのアクセスという意味は共通なので、2行目と大きく異なることはありません。プロパティsizeは、CGSize型を返します。

以上から、Q1に対する回答は、「ドット文法（Dot Syntax）を使って、画面のサイズを、CGSize型で出力する」となります。

```
var _piece = [UIImageView]()
var _data = [Int]()
// →Q2「上の２文の『[xxxx]()』はどういう意味（文法）でしょうか？」
```

Swiftでは、大括弧（[]）を、Array（配列）とDictionary（辞書）に対して使用します。
C言語では、配列の宣言を

```
int array[];
```

とします。同様の宣言をSwiftで行うと、

```
var array: [Int]
```

となります。配列の要素の型を大括弧で囲む形で、配列の型とします。
Swiftでは、オブジェクト（クラス、インスタンス、構造体、列挙子、配列、辞書、文字列、整数、実数などを包括した表現）のイニシアライザ（Javaでは、コンストラクタと呼ぶのだと思います。）を、

```
型名()
```

という書式で行います。

```
// 整数Intのイニシアライズ
var value = Int()
// 文字列Stringのイニシアライズ
var string = String()
```

なので、Q2の答えは、

```
var _piece = [UIImageView]()
// UIImageView型を要素とする配列のイニシアライザ
var _data = [Int]()
// Int型を要素とする配列のイニシアライザ
```

となります。
ちなみに、かっこの中を空のままにすると、要素数0（空）の配列を生成します。

Answer (score 2):

**A1**: `let sCREEn = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size`の意味

**端末の画面のサイズを変数`sCREEn`に代入している**

1. `UIScreen.mainScreen()`で端末の画面* をオブジェクトとして取得
2. `UIScreen`オブジェクトのプロパティ`bounds`は端末の画面のローカル領域を示す
3. `bounds`に含まれる`size`は領域の広さを示す

<sub>* `UIScreen.mainScreen()`で取得できるオブジェクトは **端末の画面** のそれであると決められている</sub>

---

**A2**: `[xxxx]()`の意味

**`xxxx`型の空の配列を作成している**

以下のように書くと「`xxxx`型の配列を作成し、空の配列で初期化」となる

```
var array: [xxxx] = [] // arrayは任意の変数名
```

以下のように書くと「型が未定な変数を作成し、`xxxx`型の空の配列で初期化」となる

```
var array = [xxxx]()
```

結果、どちらも同様に`xxxx`型の配列が作成される